# Get-MailboxDatabase -status throws DataValidationException

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

When calling

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -Status
```

we get the following Exception in one environment:

> You must provide a value for this property. Property Name: HostServer
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Get-MailboxDatabase], DataValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1401E8AF,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.GetMailboxDatabase
>   + PSComputerName : XXXXXXXXX

We tried to execute the command while connected to a server having (only) the hub transport role and on a server having the mailbox role. Both throw the same error. When we omit the -Status parameter, we get the list of all databases as expected (but without the required status information).

Since the command fails on 2 different servers of the same Organization while it is working in all other organizations, I suspect the problem is originated in AD. Any idea what could cause the issue?

Comment: Did you tried to specify the server? Sometimes (in migration scenarios) the console might get confused where to check. So please try "Get-MailboxDatabase -Identity MailboxDatabase01 -Server Server01 -Status | Format-List" or something else.

Comment: Yes, when a server is specified, the command returns the databases stored on that server. I'm aware that I could potentially workaround by iterating the servers and then request the databases from each of those servers but I really need to figure out what causes the cmdlet to fail if i run it with the parameterset mentioned above since according to the documentation of Get-MailboxDatabase it should work.